# Ranked model with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application in Rails 5, everything works fine until it passes to the controller, which assigns numbers negative, without order of view. I have reviewed many times my code but can not find the problem. Gem Can be incompatible with the version of Rails?

In my coffeescript have this, work fine, has reviewed:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->

    $ ->
    if $('.sortable').length > 0
      table_width = $('.sortable').width()
      cells = $('.table').find('tr')[0].cells.length
      desired_width = table_width / cells + 'px'
      $('.table td').css('width', desired_width)

      $('.sortable').sortable(
        axis: 'y'
        items: '.item'
        cursor: 'move'

        sort: (e, ui) ->
          ui.item.addClass('active-item-shadow')
        stop: (e, ui) ->
          ui.item.removeClass('active-item-shadow')
          # highlight the row on drop to indicate an update
          ui.item.children('td').effect('highlight', {}, 1000)
        update: (e, ui) ->
          item_id = ui.item.data('item-id')
          position = ui.item.index() # this will not work with paginated items, as the index is zero on every page
          console.log position
          $.ajax(
            type: 'POST'
            url: '/colors/update_secuencia'
            dataType: 'json'
            data: { color: {color_id: item_id, secuencia_position: position } }
          )
      )
  return
```

I leave my code of the controller, where I try to multiply by 1 to move the number to a positive

```
def update_secuencia
  @color = Color.find(color_params[:color_id])    
  @color.secuencia_position = color_params[:color_position].to_i * (-1)
  @color.save 

  head :no_content
end
```

I don't have more configuration in the controller

I have used this tutorial, http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/

This is documentation of gem https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model

Any idea or suggestion?